# Acting on the day of week

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hopefully somebody can offer some suggestions here, I'm working with a PostgreSQL database.

The purpose of this query is to determine users who are currently allowed access. The goal is to provide a date and time range as input, and see user accounts who could be allowed access during the specified date and time range.

The table is setup like this, with time columns for 'start time' and 'end time' which specifies the time range a user is allowed. Then a boolean column for each day of the week, which designates if that user is allowed access for the time range on that day.

```
   [START TIME]    [END TIME]   [MON]   [TUES]     [WED]     [THURS]     [FRI]    [SAT]     [SUN]
    09:00:00       11:00:00     True     True      True       True       True     False     False
```

Now, this seems simple, but in my mind the system needs to first know what day of the week it is to then use a long drawn out 'case when' to say 'if date entered is a monday and table.mon = true for this user, then this user meets the criteria.

So far, I have something like this:

```
DO $$
DECLARE 

--Specify 'variables'
active_date timestamp := '2020-10-4';
start_time time := '00:00:00';
end_time time := '23:59:00';
day_of_week text := to_char(active_date, 'day');

BEGIN
    CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_output ON COMMIT DROP AS
    select distinct
    date(account.lastupdated) as "Date",
    concat(to_char(account.start_time, 'HH:MI'), ' - ', to_char(account.end_time, 'HH:MI')) as "Time Range"
    from account
    where account.lastupdated >= active_date AND account.lastupdated < active_date + interval '1 day'
    and account.start_time >= start_time AND account.end_time <= end_time;
END $$;

SELECT * FROM temp_output;
```

What I'm stuck on, is that the output should only show values if the date entered has a boolean "True" for each row returned.

Something like:

```
case when day_of_week = 'sunday' and account.sun = "True" then ...
     when day_of_week = 'monday' and account.mon = "True" then...
     when day_of_week = 'tuesday' and account.tues = "True" then...
```

But how can I implement this logic for the entire set of results based on whatever date is entered?

Comment: Maybe the best way to handle this would be at the bottom with a long where clause? where (day_of_week = 'sunday' and account.sun = True) or (day_of_week = 'monday' and account.mon = True) or...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you need to do is determine if a row matches a particular day, check if the appropriate column is true.

```
-- Check if this is valid for Monday
where mon
```

---

Using individual columns to store list items doesn't work out well in SQL, as you're discovering.

In traditional SQL you'd have a join table to store which days this time applied.

```
create table schedule (
  id bigserial primary key,
  start_time time not null,
  end_time time not null
);

create table schedule_days (
  schedule_id bigint not null references schedule(id),
  day text not null
);

insert into schedule (start_time, end_time) values ('09:00', '11:00');
insert into schedule_days (schedule_id, day) values
  (1, 'Mon'), (1, 'Tues'), (1, 'Wed'), (1, 'Thurs'), (1, 'Fri');

select *
from schedule s
join schedule_days sd on s.id = sd.schedule_id
where current_time between start_time and end_time
  and day = $1
```

We can improve on this by using an enum to store the days. This ensures only correct values are added. It saves storage space because they're really stored as integers. And they can continue to be queried as strings.

```
create type day_of_week as ('Mon', 'Tues', 'Wed', 'Thurs', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun');

create table schedule_days (
  schedule_id bigint not null references schedule(id),
  day day_of_week not null
);
```

---

Alternatively, you can use a single [array column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html) for the days.

```
create table schedule (
  id bigserial primary key,
  start_time time not null,
  end_time time not null,
  days day_of_week[] not null
);

insert into schedule (start_time, end_time, days)
  values ('09:00', '11:00', array['Mon', 'Tues', 'Wed', 'Thurs', 'Fri']);
```

Then after you normalize your input, check if it's included in the days array.

```
select *
from schedule s
where current_time between start_time and end_time
  and days @> array['Tues']
```

Comment: Thank you for the insight. Unfortunately I didn't create (nor do I even maintain) this database. It's a db for a moderately popular app and they're contracting me out to create reports for them... sooo here I am!

Comment: @boog In that case, to determine if it's valid for a particular day, simply check if the appropriate day column is true. `where mon` to check if it's valid for Monday.